# Completely delete Liferay Workspace in eclipse?

Tags: liferay, liferay-ide

I create a Liferay Workspace Project in eClipse. After that, I delete the workspace project in the eClipse.

The problem is that I can't create another new Liferay Workspace Project after deleted it.
It just showed "A Liferay Workspace project already exists in this Eclipse instance."

How can I completely delete the "Liferay Workspace Project"?

Eric

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell you an alternative: just create a new eclipse workspace. It's a lot quicker than figuring out where the tool set saves this information